# Bash remove an exact line and number of characters from a large file

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I want to match and replace a multi-line regex in a large DB dump in a relatively memory efficient manner. The closest solution I could find is:

```sh
pcregrep -M --line-offsets --buffer-size=100000000 '^COPY "my_app"\."spatial_ref_sys"\s\(.+?\) FROM stdin;(.|\n)*?\\.$' my_app-dump.sql
```

This will use a max of 280MB of memory and (due to the `--line-offsets` option) give me this output: `1123175:0,105`. This indicates the line number (1123175), character offset from the start of the line (0), and the length of the matched string (105). This match *will* span multiple lines.

My question is: What is the "best" way to open the file, remove the offending snippet, and save it? I would prefer something that can be done in bash alone, but that's not required.

## Context

I am migrating from an EC2 installed Postgres database to an AWS RDS Postgres database. One of the problems I encountered is that when I use `pg_dump` then some of the commands it issues requires superuser privileges, which RDS does not provide me with. I have already removed multiple offending SQL statements via `sed`. None of these statements are critical to our application, but leaving them in will cause the restore to fail.

## Current Working Solution

```sh
perl -i -0pe 's/^COPY "my_app"\."spatial_ref_sys"\s\(.+?\) FROM stdin;(.|\n)*?\\.$//gmi' my_app-dump.sql
```

This uses perl to do the regex find and replace directly on the DB dump. However, this loads the entire file into memory which can be 6GB in size. Testing this from a locally installed Postgres DB works fine, because I have the memory to spare, but I will have to run this on an AWS EC2 instance, so I'll have to spin up a very powerful instance to do this migration. I feel this is unnecessary. I already know that `pcregrep` can do the matching with 280MB or memory, I merely need to remove the found snippet which I can't figure out how to do.

## Demo and Sample Input

[This demo](https://regex101.com/r/IpTGmV/2) on regex101 shows exactly what I want to achieve. It matches the correct lines and substitutes them with empty strings.

In addition here is a snippet from the DB dump:

```sql
COPY "my_app"."schema_migrations" ("version") FROM stdin;
20170213125755
20180213083924
20180219070405
20180219102435
20180220074712
20180221082708
20180221104015
20180523211327
20190213080433
20190218070455
20190226084814
20190625083212
20190704092807
20190705070442
20190711073923
20190718095547
\.


--
-- Data for Name: spatial_ref_sys; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: my_app; Owner: -
--

COPY "my_app"."spatial_ref_sys" ("srid", "auth_name", "auth_srid", "srtext", "proj4text") FROM stdin;
\.
```

Out of the above only this should match the regex:

```sql
COPY "my_app"."spatial_ref_sys" ("srid", "auth_name", "auth_srid", "srtext", "proj4text") FROM stdin;
\.
```

All of these should also match, even if they aren't in the DB dump:

```sql
COPY "my_app"."spatial_ref_sys" ("srid", "auth_name", "auth_srid", "srtext", "proj4text") FROM stdin;
asdf
bla
\.

COPY "my_app"."spatial_ref_sys" (foo, bar) FROM stdin;
\.

COPY "my_app"."spatial_ref_sys" ("foasd 234$", "qwdmc") FROM stdin;
asdjnaksjdnkajnd&(*)-
alkc n;{}
\.
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input. The volunteers answering shouldn't have to each make up their own (and also chance getting it wrong).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid reading in the whole file in memory, you can try write to the output file as you scan the input file. For example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    my $input_fn = 'my_app-dump.sql';
    my $output_fn = 'my_app_filtered.sql';
    Filter->new(
        input_fn => $input_fn,
        output_fn => $output_fn
    );
}

package Filter;
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my ( $class, %args ) = @_;
    my $self = bless \%args, $class;

    $self->open_files();
    $self->filter_io_loop();
    $self->close_files();
}

sub filter_io_loop {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    my $fh = $self->{fh};
    my $ofh = $self->{ofh};
    while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        if ( $line =~ /^COPY "my_app"\."spatial_ref_sys"\s\([^)]*\) FROM stdin;/ ) {
            $self->skip_lines( $fh, $line );
        }
        else {
            print $ofh $line;
        }
    }
}

sub skip_lines {
    my ( $self,  $fh, $line ) = @_;

    while (1) {
        return if $line =~ /\\\.$/;
        $line = <$fh>;
        if (!defined $line) {
            warn "Warning: EOF reached while searching for end of COPY\n";
            return;
        }
    }
}


sub close_files {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    close $self->{ofh};
    close $self->{fh};
}

sub open_files {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    my $input_fn = $self->{input_fn};
    my $output_fn = $self->{output_fn};
    open ( my $fh, '<', $input_fn ) or die "Could not open file '$input_fn': $!";
    open ( my $ofh, '>', $output_fn ) or die "Could not open file '$output_fn': $!";
    $self->{fh} = $fh;
    $self->{ofh} = $ofh;
}
```